# the default template for go lang "aws-go" in the serverless framwork isn't working

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

hello everyone :) noob here, I am having trouble invoking pre-built aws-go template function that i have deployed using the serverless framework.

not sure if it's relevant but here some details about my system

`````
                   -`                    malup@mangulangot 
                  .o+`                   ----------------- 
                 `ooo/                   OS: Arch Linux x86_64 
                `+oooo:                  Host: GV62 8RD REV:1.0 
               `+oooooo:                 Kernel: 6.0.12-arch1-1 
               -+oooooo+:                Uptime: 20 hours, 51 mins 
             `/:-:++oooo+:               Packages: 1578 (pacman) 
            `/++++/+++++++:              Shell: zsh 5.9 
           `/++++++++++++++:             Resolution: 1920x1200 
          `/+++ooooooooooooo/`           DE: GNOME 43.2 
         ./ooosssso++osssssso+`          WM: Mutter 
        .oossssso-````/ossssss+`         WM Theme: Adwaita 
       -osssssso.      :ssssssso.        Theme: Juno-v40 [GTK2/3] 
      :osssssss/        osssso+++.       Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
     /ossssssss/        +ssssooo/-       Terminal: kitty 
   `/ossssso+/:-        -:/+osssso+-     CPU: Intel i5-8300H (8) @ 4.000GHz 
  `+sso+:-`                 `.-/+oso:    GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile 
 `++:.                           `-/+/   GPU: Intel CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] 
 .`                                 `/   Memory: 11563MiB / 15842MiB
`````

i have

- Nodejs: `v19.0.0`
- Go: `go version go1.19.4 linux/amd64`
- aws cli: `aws-cli/2.9.8 Python/3.9.11 Linux/6.0.12-arch1-1 exe/x86_64.arch prompt/off`
- serverless framework:

```
Framework Core: 3.25.1
Plugin: 6.2.2
SDK: 4.3.2
```

i keep getting this error message

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ExitError",
    "errorMessage": "RequestId: ac441b76-f8af-4565-9d46-8d8849efdf9c Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1"
}
Environment: linux, node 19.0.0, framework 3.25.1, plugin 6.2.2, SDK 4.3.2
Credentials: Local, "default" profile
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
Invoked function failed
```

here are the exact steps i have taken to deploy the function/s,

1. created an IAM user name in aws console ui in the browser with `Access key - Programmatic access` as credential type
2. clicked on `Attach existing policies directly` and checked the box for `AdministratorAcess` and finished creating the user
3. ran `aws configure` and entered the

   - `AWS Access Key ID`
   - `AWS Secret Access Key`
   - entered `us-east-1` for the region
   - and entered `json` for the output format
4. ran `serverless create -t aws-go -p backend` to create a project structure called `backend`
5. `cd backend`
6. `go mod init backend` to create the mod file
7. `go mod tidy` to resolve dependencies
8. `make`
9. `serverless deploy`

no errors have occurred and everything seemed fine.
now i run `serverless invoke -f hello`
and i get that error message

if i click on the `Test` button from the aws lambda console for the function it also fails with this is as the log message

```
/var/task/bin/hello: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /var/task/bin/hello)
/var/task/bin/hello: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /var/task/bin/hello)
2022/12/17 21:44:41 exit status 1
/var/task/bin/hello: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /var/task/bin/hello)
/var/task/bin/hello: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /var/task/bin/hello)
2022/12/17 21:44:41 exit status 1
START RequestId: bdc3fd91-c5a8-4427-ab84-2eebba760853 Version: $LATEST
RequestId: bdc3fd91-c5a8-4427-ab84-2eebba760853 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
END RequestId: bdc3fd91-c5a8-4427-ab84-2eebba760853
```

how do i go about resolving this issue please help :(

Answer (score 1):

solved by changing the make file according to the instructions on this forum
https://forum.serverless.com/t/hello-world-results-in-internal-server-error/13447

```
build:
    env CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/hello hello/main.go
    env CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/world world/main.go
```